# Xib referencing two xibs as view

Tags: ios, xib

How can I set a ViewController that will display one view or another depending on some case ?

I have `ViewControllerA.xib` and `ViewControllerB.xib`. Both have a `UITableView`, and some logic. I would like to load `ViewControllerAB` (via xib or programmatically), that display a loading screen while I get data from the network. When I have the data, I decide which view to display, A or B. I do this via `addSubview`, but the touch isn't responsive when I tap a row in the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController A and B did you set the tableView's delegate and datasourse to the respective controller?
It might be the problem, because your solution (with addSubview) should work. Can you post some code if it doesn't solve your problem?